# How do I refactor my Apex code with SOQL queries to meet the governor limits?

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

I don't know how I can refactor the following code to be able to import a large file, say of thousand records:

```
for (Integer index = 0; index < csvFileLines.size(); ++index) {
    String[] csvRecordValues = csvFileLines[index].split(',');
    List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Name = :csvRecordValues[10] Limit 1];
    if (contacts.isEmpty()) {
        Contact aContact = new Contact();
        List<String> nameTokens = csvRecordValues[10].split('\\s');
        aContact.FirstName = nameTokens[0];
        aContact.LastNAme = nameTokens[1];
        try {
            insert aContact;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error creating contact!'));
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }                        
    myOtherObject.ContactLookup = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :csvRecordValues[10] Limit 1].Id;
}
```

The main point I don't understand is how to perform the lookup linkage, i.e. `myOtherObject.ContactLookup = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :csvRecordValues[10] Limit 1].Id;` if I do the SOQL outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here - DML in loop and 2 SOQL in loop. 
Check pseudocode below:

```
//Step 1 - query all contacts
Set<String> contactNames = new Set<String>();
for (Integer index = 0; index < csvFileLines.size(); ++index) {
    contactNames.add(csvFileLines[index].split(',').get(10);
}
List<Contact> all_contacts = [SELECT Id, Name From Contact WHERE Name in :contactNames];
Map<Name,Contact> allContactsByNames = new Map<String,Contact>();
for(Contact c : all_contacts){
    allContactsByNames.add(c.Name, c);
}
//step 2 - pupulate map with key equal to contact name and value as contact
//in case if there are no contact - create it
List<Contact> contact_to_insert = new List<Contact>();
for (Integer index = 0; index < csvFileLines.size(); ++index) {
    String[] csvRecordValues = csvFileLines[index].split(',');
    Contact c = allContactsByNames.get(csvRecordValues.get(10));
    if (c == null) {
        Contact aContact = new Contact();
        List<String> nameTokens = csvRecordValues[10].split('\\s');
        aContact.FirstName = nameTokens[0];
        aContact.LastNAme = nameTokens[1];
        allContactsByNames.add(aContact.Name, aContact);
        contact_to_insert.add(aContact);
    } 
    //myOtherObject.ContactLookup = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :csvRecordValues[10] Limit 1].Id;
}
//step 3 - insert newly added contacts
insert contact_to_insert;//add error catching

//step 4 - we have all its now. Populate relationship
for (Integer index = 0; index < csvFileLines.size(); ++index) {
    String[] csvRecordValues = csvFileLines[index].split(',');
    Contact c = allContactsByNames.get(csvRecordValues.get(10));
    myOtherObject.ContactLookup = c.Id;
}
```

Here are some good practices about apex development - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices.

P.S. I have assumed that all the contact names are uniq. But you definitely need to think about mechanism how to process that based on what are your requirements.